# Reducing RichFaces Script and Style Loads

Tags: richfaces

I'm currently developing an e-commerce application using RichFaces 3.3.2. The users have mentioned that the experience has been lagging lately and we're looking for ways to speed up page load times.

We noticed that RichFaces is loading some unnecessary scripts onto our pages. We're using the LoadScriptStrategy and LoadStyleStrategy of "DEFAULT" so that they're loaded on-demand, but it still loads a lot of junk that we don't use.

I'm wondering if RichFaces has the ability to sort through what is and isn't used in my web page? Either that or some way of seeing what resources each of my pages is using; that way I can set my Strategies to "NONE" and manually import what I need.

Basically I'm trying to avoid combing through each page and analyzing exactly what is used. Any advice or previous experience?

Thanks in advance.

-Nick

Answer (score 0):

DEFAULT - should load (and unload) only resources which are needed. You can try NONE but then you will need to figure out yourself what to load.

You say the application is lagging, are you sure it's because of scripts/styles loaded and not something else?

Comment: My understanding was that DEFAULT loaded all scripts and/or styles when the first "call" to each respective bundle was made. Does RichFaces have that kind of awareness to pull in only the resources I'm using on my page?

There's a lot going on within my page, I'm sure other things are responsible for the lag as well. This just seemed like a major area that could help improve performance. Thanks for the response!

Comment: DEFAULT - is on demand, get only what you need. There is ALL - in that case it will load everything in one file but only once.